# Tricky integral limit

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

Please help me to solve the following limit using high-school methods(no approximations or DCT). I was thinking to use the squeeze theorem but I can't find the best boundaries to evaluate it.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1+x+x^n}dx$$

Comment: @Hayk Both of those answers use DCT.

Comment: Thanks for the help but this problem must be done without DCT/approximations.

Comment: @Leucippus this problem must be done without DCT...

Comment: @Andrei: what things are allowed in "high school" methods? Is Monotone Convergence okay? That is close to the Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: Squeeze theorem, inequalities...

Comment: The problem is addressed to high school students

Comment: If you are doing integration problems, it is unclear why you are not allowed to use approximations, MCT, or DCT, so it is hard to construct an answer.

Comment: Because the problem is for high schoolers who don't know such techniques...This problem is for admission to a university  in Romania

Comment: Look at my answer to the duplicate and see if you can figure the difference between $\int_0^1\frac{x^{1/n}}{1+x^{1/n}+x}\,\mathrm{d}x$ and $\int_0^1\frac1{2+x}\,\mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: @Andrei: you have to let us know what is allowed since I am sure that curricula at different high schools vary.

Comment: You can't apply Taylor expansion or things like this, DCT or anything Lebesgue related (I think). You can use substitution and squeeze theorems or inequalities.

Comment: @Andrei: I have added an approach that should be basic enough. It is simply what I suggested above.

Comment: @robjohn I understand the right inequality, but I cannot find the left one which must approach to ln(3/2) when integrating..please help

Comment: @Andrei: the whole point of the later approach is that the difference between $\int_0^1\frac{x^{1/n}}{1+x^{1/n}+x}\,\mathrm{d}x$ and $\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{2+x}$ is less than $\frac1{2n+2}$. Is that basic enough for high school?

Comment: It is, but I think you are being sarcastic :(

Comment: @Andrei: I only asked because you said Taylor expansion is not allowed, but that is usually introduced before integration (though a rigorous treatment does require integration). I don't have a good idea if everything in that approach is allowed. I'm sorry if my comment sounded sarcastic.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).